# ASP.NET Core API receive JsonArray and post objects to DB (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, arrays, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core

this may be a simple one, but don't hate on the newbie question:

I have a device sending a JsonArray to my API on ASP.NET Core, example below:

```
[{
    "SSID":"test01",
    "Channel":"13",
    "RSSI":"-24",
    "RequiresPassword":true,
    "Hidden":false,
    "Sensor":"test",
    "Location": "test"
},
{
    "SSID":"test02",
    "Channel":"13",
    "RSSI":"-24",
    "RequiresPassword":true,
    "Hidden":false,
    "Sensor":"test",
    "Location": "test"
}]
```

However, I am struggling to get the data stored to the DB - code below:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<Network>> PostNetwork(List<Network> JSONarray)
    {
        DateTime nowUTC = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        bool knownNetwork = false;
        foreach (Network network in JSONarray)
        {
            var uniqueNetwork = _context.UniqueNetworks.SingleOrDefault(n => n.SSID == network.SSID);
            if (_context.Networks.Where(n => n.SSID == (network.SSID + " | " + network.Channel)).Count() > 824) // threshold for known networks is 824 identifications
            {
                knownNetwork = true;
                var uniqueItem = _context.UniqueNetworks.Find(uniqueNetwork.ID);
                {
                    uniqueItem.LastSeenUTC = nowUTC;
                    uniqueItem.Sensor = network.Sensor;
                    uniqueItem.Location = network.Location;
                };
                _context.UniqueNetworks.Update(uniqueItem);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            else if (_context.Networks.Where(n => n.SSID == (network.SSID + " | " + network.Channel)).Count() > 1)
            {
                knownNetwork = false;
                var recurringItem = new Network
                {
                    ID = network.ID,
                    SSID = network.SSID + " | " + network.Channel,
                    Channel = network.Channel,
                    RequiresPassword = network.RequiresPassword,
                    Hidden = network.Hidden,
                    KnownNetwork = knownNetwork,
                    RSSI = network.RSSI,
                    Sensor = network.Sensor,
                    Location = network.Location,
                    TimestampUTC = nowUTC
                };
                _context.Networks.Add(recurringItem);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return CreatedAtAction("GetNetwork", new { id = network.ID }, recurringItem);
            }
            else
            {
                knownNetwork = false;
                var uniqueItem = new UniqueNetwork
                {
                    ID = network.ID,
                    SSID = network.SSID,
                    FirstSeenUTC = nowUTC,
                    LastSeenUTC = nowUTC,
                    Sensor = network.Sensor,
                    Location = network.Location
                };
                _context.UniqueNetworks.Add(uniqueItem);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                var newItem = new Data
                {
                    Activity = "New network detected: " + network.SSID.ToString(),
                    Sensor = network.Sensor,
                    Location = network.Location,
                    TimestampUTC = nowUTC
                };
                _context.Activities.Add(newItem);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            var item = new Network
            {
                ID = network.ID,
                SSID = network.SSID + " | " + network.Channel,
                Channel = network.Channel,
                RequiresPassword = network.RequiresPassword,
                Hidden = network.Hidden,
                KnownNetwork = knownNetwork,
                RSSI = network.RSSI,
                Sensor = network.Sensor,
                Location = network.Location,
                TimestampUTC = nowUTC
            };
            _context.Networks.Add(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction("GetNetwork", new { id = network.ID }, item);
        }
        
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return NoContent();
    }
```

I've managed to get it working by sending a single JsonObject using more or less the standard code coming out of the box when scaffolding a controller, but I can't seem to get it working like this.

**Update: Working code for single JsonObject** (below)

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<Network>> PostNetwork(Network network)
    {
        DateTime nowUTC = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        var uniqueNetwork = _context.UniqueNetworks.SingleOrDefault(n => n.SSID == network.SSID);
        bool knownNetwork = false;
        if (_context.Networks.Where(n => n.SSID == (network.SSID + " | " + network.Channel)).Count() > 824) // threshold for known networks is 824 identifications
        {
            knownNetwork = true;
            var uniqueItem = _context.UniqueNetworks.Find(uniqueNetwork.ID);
            {
                uniqueItem.LastSeenUTC = nowUTC;
                uniqueItem.Sensor = network.Sensor;
                uniqueItem.Location = network.Location;
            };
            _context.UniqueNetworks.Update(uniqueItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else if (_context.Networks.Where(n => n.SSID == (network.SSID + " | " + network.Channel)).Count() > 1)
        {
            knownNetwork = false;
            var recurringItem = new Network
            {
                ID = network.ID,
                SSID = network.SSID + " | " + network.Channel,
                Channel = network.Channel,
                RequiresPassword = network.RequiresPassword,
                Hidden = network.Hidden,
                KnownNetwork = knownNetwork,
                RSSI = network.RSSI,
                Sensor = network.Sensor,
                Location = network.Location,
                TimestampUTC = nowUTC
            };
            _context.Networks.Add(recurringItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction("GetNetwork", new { id = network.ID }, recurringItem);
        }
        else
        {
            knownNetwork = false;
            var uniqueItem = new UniqueNetwork
            {
                ID = network.ID,
                SSID = network.SSID,
                FirstSeenUTC = nowUTC,
                LastSeenUTC = nowUTC,
                Sensor = network.Sensor,
                Location = network.Location
            };
            _context.UniqueNetworks.Add(uniqueItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            var newItem = new Data
            {
                Activity = "New network detected: " + network.SSID.ToString(),
                Sensor = network.Sensor,
                Location = network.Location,
                TimestampUTC = nowUTC
            };
            _context.Activities.Add(newItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        var item = new Network
        {
            ID = network.ID,
            SSID = network.SSID + " | " + network.Channel,
            Channel = network.Channel,
            RequiresPassword = network.RequiresPassword,
            Hidden = network.Hidden,
            KnownNetwork = knownNetwork,
            RSSI = network.RSSI,
            Sensor = network.Sensor,
            Location = network.Location,
            TimestampUTC = nowUTC
        };
        _context.Networks.Add(item);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction("GetNetwork", new { id = network.ID }, item);
    }
```

Comment: What you mean about about using more or less the standard code coming out of the box when scaffolding a controller?  Do you face any error message when generating the codes?

Comment: @brando zhang - I updated the above with the working code that is able to process a single JsonObject at a time. The goal would be to send a JsonArray to the API and have it processed/saved to the DB item by item. I am not seeing any error message as the API is responding with a 400 - I assume it is not expecting a JsonArray.